# Mac asked me to force shutdown my laptop

Tags: macos, error, shutdown, kernel-panic

[image: screenshot]

I've never seen that.
A kind of shade slowly took over my screen and a message asked me to hold the power button until the macbook shuts down.

Here is the error report:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  412658 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    *****

Tue Nov  8 19:08:57 2011
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80002c266d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800023fb2f, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x000000003acc4044, CR4: 0x00000000000206e0
RAX: 0x000000000000fffe, RBX: 0x0000000000000002, RCX: 0x0000000001000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000002
RSP: 0xffffff812b5bbe40, RBP: 0xffffff812b5bbe90, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffff7f81e7e74b, R9:  0x0000000086954c8d, R10: 0x00007fff887e8386, R11: 0xffffff80002d8220
R12: 0xffffff80006d5160, R13: 0xffffff812b5bbea8, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff8015e97768
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff800023fb2f, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Faulting CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff812b5bbb00 : 0xffffff8000220702 
0xffffff812b5bbb80 : 0xffffff80002c266d 
0xffffff812b5bbd20 : 0xffffff80002d7a1d 
0xffffff812b5bbd40 : 0xffffff800023fb2f 
0xffffff812b5bbe90 : 0xffffff80005322d6 
0xffffff812b5bbee0 : 0xffffff8000533e3c 
0xffffff812b5bbf20 : 0xffffff8000533f77 
0xffffff812b5bbf50 : 0xffffff80005caa9b 
0xffffff812b5bbfb0 : 0xffffff80002d8363 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: OsTrack

Mac OS version:
11C74

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: ****
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 13929880995019
last loaded kext at 9693739721244: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs    1.7.1 (addr 0xffffff7f80791000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 9856808335126: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.1.15 (addr 0xffffff7f8078d000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   82
com.parallels.kext.prl_hid_hook 6.0 12106.692267
com.parallels.kext.prl_hypervisor   6.0 12106.692267
com.parallels.kext.prl_usb_connect  6.0 12106.692267
com.parallels.kext.prl_vnic 6.0 12106.692267
com.parallels.kext.prl_netbridge    6.0 12106.692267
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   2.4.0
com.apple.nke.pppoe 1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.4d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.42
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.1.3f7
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.1.3f7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.26
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   7.1.4
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 7.1.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.5d4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.0.16
com.apple.GeForce   7.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  225.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 225.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   512.20.18
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.8.9
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.0.8b2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 167.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   167.0.0
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.7
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.1.3f7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.1f4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.1.3f7
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.1.3f7
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.3fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.0.16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.1d8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.5d4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.0.16
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.3
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    7.1.4
com.apple.NVDAResman    7.1.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.2
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.1f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.1f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.1f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 227.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  3.9.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   411.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 403
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.5.3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.0d5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  165.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.4
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0C, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f16
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.18)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.1f4, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: ST9500420ASG, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfa130000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0236, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0xfd110000 / 4
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 3
```

Should I worry? What does it mean? What should I do?

Comment: Looks like a kernel panic. What is your question?

Comment: I added now at the bottom "Should I worry? What does it mean? What should I do?". The answer from @daviesgeek seems like a good example of answers I was looking for.

Comment: It is frightening the first time it happens to you, though.

Comment: looks like a bad memory card to me...mine was.

Comment: Could be one of the non-Apple kexts as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your screenshots, it looks like you had a kernel panic. A kernel panic is an action which an OS takes due to a fatal error. More info on Wikipedia about [kernel panics.](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=kernel%20panic)

From [Apple's support doc about kernel panics:](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3742)

> In most cases, kernel panics are not caused by an issue with your Mac. They are most likely caused by an issue external to your Mac. If the kernel panic doesn't happen again within a few weeks, you don't need to troubleshoot further.

All you need to do is hold down the power button on your Mac until it shuts down. Then, start it back up. If you are still experiencing kernel panics, Apple recommends that you boot up in safe mode to see if you still have kernel panics. Read the support doc for more information.

You shouldn't be too worried about a kernel panic. Usually they are caused by external things, and can be resolved by rebooting. If you continually get kernel panics, then you should start worrying. The support doc gives some advanced troubleshooting for kernel panics.